# Using and decoding raw SSL data as proof

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, decoding

I would like to decode and store raw SSL/TLS data in order to prove something in the future, i think it will be better if i describe it by an example:

1) There is a remote REST endpoint that is accessible via SSL and provides some useful data. This endpoint is controlled by some third party and i have no control over it.

2) I issue a GET request to this endpoint and store the raw SSL traffic of the response in one file and then the decoded ssl traffic in another file

3) Additionally i save the SSL certificate of this endpoint in a separate file (i guess this operation would only need to be done once)

If i understand correctly when i have all the data from the steps above and in the future, when another third  party asks me for a proof that there was certain data on the remote server at some point in the past i could:

1) Present them with the certificate i saved (step 3). Since this certificate is signed by a well known authority there is almost zero chance that i could forge it

2) Present them with the RAW SSL data along with a way to decode it using the certificate above

3) In the decoded REST response headers remote server time should also be present.

Therefore if i am not mistaken i would be able to prove, with almost no doubt, that at some point in the past there was that certain piece of data on the remote party's server even  if the remote server itself is no longer operational.

Therefore i can use raw SSL data to prove that something existed on the remote server in past. And there is very little chance of someone challeging this claim because forging the response data or headers would mean that i was able to break the SSL encryption.

Is there a way to automate such scenarios? I mean is there a way to record raw SSL data in a form that would allow it to be easily decoded later?

I have tried using firefox/chrome browser along with the sslkeylog files and sniffing the traffic using wireshark - it actually works, but is there a way to automate it using some kind of REST library since using firefox and recording SSL keys each time can be troublesome - there may be a need to store thousands of these requests per hour and doing it manually would be a full time job, additionally i am not sure if there is a way to prove that these keys stored  in ssskeylog files actually match the certificate of the remote server...

Comment: The technology you are looking for is called a digital signature. Your present approach is neither suitable nor feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot prove the server sent the data. For example, with TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 as the ciphersuite, you can forge all data from both sides in an entire TLS session without even contacting the server. And the server side can also produce such a forgery. As noted by EJP, the only thing you can't forge is data that is *signed*. With RSA ciphersuites the only thing signed are the certificates, but they don't change and are not cryptographically bound to a TLS session.

Other ciphersuites may involve some signed handshake data, but TLS was not designed to provide non-repudiation so I doubt it does by accident.

Comment: You are correct and I've deleted my answer. All what is needed to create fake application data is the master secret which is known by the client. Therefore the client can fake any data and claim the server has sent these.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I knew you'd either delete your answer or tell me why I was wrong, in which case I would have deleted my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So i assume there is no way to prove that the data came from a certain server if it does not sign the data and only uses TLS?

Comment: @Pma: You can prove the data came from *either* the client or the server, but you can't prove anything more specific.

Comment: @Pma: tlsnotary does sound promising. It looks geared toward allowing the client to prove it generated specified HTTPs web traffic rather than allowing the server to prove something. And of course I am unaware of any security analysis of the tlsnotary protocol.